# Spark CSV read/write for empty field

Tags: csv, apache-spark, dataframe

I want to write by Dataframe's empty field as empty but it always writes as `NULL`. I want to write NULLS as `?` and empty as empty/blank. Same while reading from a csv.

```
val df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(Seq(
    (0, "a"),
    (1, "b"),
    (2, "c"),
    (3, ""),
    (4, null)
))    

scala> df.show

|  0|   a|
|  1|   b|
|  2|   c|
|  3|    |
|  4|null|   
+---+----+

df.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("nullValue","?").save("/xxxxx/test_out")

written output :

0,a
1,b
2,c
3,?
4,?
.option("treatEmptyValuesAsNulls" , "false")
```

This option does not work.

I need the empty to write as empty

```
0,a
1,b
2,c
3,
4,?
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using sql-

I am using spark 2.2.

```
val ds= sqlContext.sql("select `_1`, case when `_2` is not null then `_2` else case when `_2` is null then '?' else case when `_2` = '' then '' end end end as val "+
      "from global_temp.test");

    ds.write.csv("<output path>");
```

Comment: here all columns requires this case condition ( i have 130 columns ) , and again while writing the empty fields will be taken as NULL by CSV write and we need to use .option("nullValue","") to write it as empty . It can be a workaround , Thanks .

Comment: If you have more fields then use `map` transformation and iterate each field in loop then apply `case statement` using UDF. I tested this and empty fields are written as blank not null.